# Passing the model as argument in the link button click using KO

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In this below example I need to pass  the model as argument in the link button click (List, range) . how to acheive this

```
<div data-bind = "foreach:modelList" >
        <div class="BDCRQuery">
            <div class= "Body" > 
                <div>
                    <select id ="SELECT" data-bind="options: Attributes, optionsText: 'AttributeName', optionsValue: 'Id', optionsCaption: 'Select Attribute...',value : SelectedAttribute"></select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>with any of the following values:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="option">
                    <a href="#"  id = "List" class="link">List</a> | <a href="#"  id= "Range" class="link">Range</a>
                </div>
               </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

luse the $parent and bind keywords

```
<a data-bind="click: $parent.functionName.bind($parent)" />
```

$parent will point to the object holding the array of modelList and it will call a function called functionName, bind will ensure that the `this` keyword is the correct context. The function will have the item clicked as the argument