# Knockout - Click Binding Behaviour

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

My question is regarding the click binding in Knockout, and why the following behaviour occurs. I have found many click binding questions on here, but not specific to the behaviour I describe below.

I understand that in Knockout click binding with parameters are executed on page load as Knockout expects a reference (to a function) so when it comes across a function call within a binding it will execute that function expecting a returned function reference to bind to. So if I returned another reference to a function, it would be that function which is executed on the elements click.

So far so good, that makes sense.

In order to see this for myself, I quickly created this:

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="click: selectImportType(1)" type="button" />
```

JS

```
var functiontest = function () {
    alert('test');
};

viewModel.selectImportType = function (type) {
    viewModel.selectedImport(type);

    return functiontest;
}
```

Upon executing this,  I have found that the 'functiontest' reference is returned to the binding as the click calls the functiontest function as expected.

Now to my confusion. I found that the selectImportType function is also called when the element is clicked. selectImportType is called first followed by a call to the functiontest function.

How is this possible? The reference resolved during the binding was to the functiontest function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your write

```
data-bind="click: selectImportType(1)"
```

the expression `selectImportType(1)` is evaluated and it returns your `functiontest` function and then it is assigned to click binding.

**Why?**

Because it's by design.

When knockout parses binding it creates bindings string evaluator that is just dynamic function:

```
function createBindingsStringEvaluator(bindingsString, options) {
  // Build the source for a function that evaluates "expression"
  // For each scope variable, add an extra level of "with" nesting
  // Example result: with(sc1) { with(sc0) { return (expression) } }
  var rewrittenBindings = ko.expressionRewriting.preProcessBindings(bindingsString, options),
      functionBody = "with($context){with($data||{}){return{" + rewrittenBindings + "}}}";
  return new Function("$context", "$element", functionBody);
}
```

In your case functionBody is:

```
"with($context){with($data||{}){return{'click':function(){return selectImportType(1) }}}}"
```

And it is evaluated to get parsedBindings (https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/v3.4.1/src/binding/bindingProvider.js#L27) like this

```
{
  "click": function(){return selectImportType(1)}
}
```

that will be passed to bindginHandler the following way:

```
var valueAccessor = getValueAccessor(bindingKey);
                                        ||
                                       click
```

So `valueAccessor` is function:

```
function(){return selectImportType(1)}
```

Then let's look at source code event binding(
https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/v3.4.1/src/binding/defaultBindings/event.js#L6-L18):

```
ko.bindingHandlers[eventName] = {
  'init': function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
     var newValueAccessor = function () {
       var result = {};
       result[eventName] = valueAccessor(); // 1
       return result;
     };
     return ko.bindingHandlers['event']['init'].call(this, element, newValueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
   }
}

ko.bindingHandlers['event'] = {
  'init' : function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
      var eventsToHandle = valueAccessor() || {}; // 2
```

As you can see the `valueAccessor` is wrapped in `newValueAccessor` and when knockout is getting handler for click event (see comment 2) `newValueAccessor` is also evaluated and you get result of execution `selectImportType(1)`

Finally `eventsToHandle` will be your `functiontest`:

```
function () {
    alert('test');
}
```

That's why the `functiontest` function is called when clicking the button

---

I guess you're looking for something like:

```
data-bind="click: selectImportType.bind($data, 1)"
```

In this case `selectImportType` function will be called only after clicking on the button element.

There are a lot of question about how to pass parameters to a function within knockout binding

- [Passing parameters to a function in knockoutjs viewmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418224/passing-parameters-to-a-function-in-knockoutjs-viewmodel)
- [Passing the model as argument in the link button click using KO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468524/passing-the-model-as-argument-in-the-link-button-click-using-ko)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand your suggestion. My question really is asking why is the `functiontest` function is called **as well as** the `selectImportType` function when clicking the button which has the binding applied to it? After evaluating and returning `functiontest` to bind to the click, I would expect just that function to be called upon clicking the button, but both functions are called somehow?